# Anonymous site as a result of entering the 'tracert 127.0.0.1' command

Tags: linux, windows, networking, command-line, router

I decided to enter this command in my windows machine in cmd : `tracert 127.0.0.1` When i saw this result i was surprised -->[image of cmd result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1bI7.png)

So as you can see in the image it is tracing route to this site : [www.blumentals.net](http://www.blumentals.net)

I want to say i never used this site and i do not know why instead of tracing route the local host , the result show me an anonymous site!

an other thing that i want to say is when i'm entering this command tracert localhost the result is this : [result for : tracert localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAA19.png)

that means it is correctly working for this command and shows me my desktop name.

I tried to use this command : `nslookup www.blumentals.net` and it is the result : [result of nslookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG0QH.png)

Can you tell me your opinion about why or how this is happening? (that why there is an anonymous site in the result of `tracert 127.0.0.1`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not tracing to `www.blumentals.net`, it's only gone a single hop as expected.

You probably have a definition in your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 www.blumentals.net
```

If it's not that, then whatever DNS systems you are using, have that defined.

Couple of reasons to do this, either to block it, or to set up a local test of that site.